# Faraday's law in superconducting loop

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, superconductivity, electromagnetic-induction

Let's say that you have a superconducting loop (resistivity=0 exactly) whose area is increasing in a uniform non-changing magnetic field.
Obviously there will be a CHANGING flux associated with the superconducting circuit and hence cyclic integral of $$E.dl$$    is non zero.
But $$E=0$$    in a superconductor which implies integral of $$E.dl$$   is zero.
How to resolve this paradox?

Comment: I've removed some comments discussing the edit history of this question.

Answer (score 3):

> Obviously there will be a CHANGING flux associated with the
>   superconducting circuit

It's true that the magnetic flux threading the loop, due to the external magnetic field, is increasing.

> How to resolve this paradox?

The circulating current changes at just the rate required to keep the *total* magnetic flux threading the loop constant.

Comment: Who is changing the current?(as there can be no electric field inside the superconductor.

Comment: @Aman, rather than asking *who* (what) is changing the current, ask what happens *if* the current doesn't change in just the right way.  In other words, imagine an infinitesimal perturbation to the rate of change of current and see that the resulting infinitesimal rate of change of flux acts to null the perturbation.

Comment: But you are just skipping over the question. What is changing the current?

Comment: Any explanation? @Hal

Comment: @Aman I don't understand your follow-up question. The supercurrent changes to cancel the induced electric field associated with the non-constant magnetic field.